# how do I restrict my android phone to just my home and work wifi?

Tags: wi-fi

My android phone keeps connecting to random public wifi's that don't work very well. So I turned off wifi completely. Is there a way to say: use wifi if either my home wifi or work wifi is available, otherwise never use wifi?

Comment: I don't think Android does what you want but I'm sure "there's an app for that."

Comment: Potential answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467789/stop-android-connecting-to-certain-wifi-networks

Answer (score 2):

Android won't connect to a wifi access point without you specifying that you want to and saving it.

Under settings, wifi, long-press on the names of any access points you don't want to connect to and choose "Forget Network".

Answer (score 1):

You can remove wifi networks under Settings -> Wireless -> Wifi -> long press on unwanted network -> remove.

Some apps like the automatic hotspot login from the german "Deutsche Telekom" are adding SSIDs to the list of known networks. If you remove such an app, the network is maybe not automatically removed.